# 2-of-2 with different wallets?

Tags: wallet, multi-signature

I've been using 2-of-2 on bitpay for some years, but relying on just one wallet, which can have its source code backdoored with malware, is very dangerous.

I've been researching about multisignature over different wallets, which makes it harder for these things to occur.

Electrum works with lots of other wallets but it's very user unfriendly. The only other one I know is BlueWallet, but its package.json dependencis worry me a lot: https://github.com/BlueWallet/BlueWallet/blob/master/package.json#L67

What would be a good solution for multisignature over 2 different wallets?

Comment: [FullyNoded](https://fullynoded.app/)

[Specter](https://github.com/cryptoadvance/specter-desktop)

[Sparrow](https://www.sparrowwallet.com/) [Nunchuk](https://nunchuk.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Specter Desktop](https://github.com/cryptoadvance/specter-desktop#creating-a-new-wallet) with the Bitcoin Core wallet and a hardware wallet for the first key and second key respectively in a 2-of-2 multisig.

For a disclaimer it states on the Specter [README](https://github.com/cryptoadvance/specter-desktop/blob/master/README.md):

> This software might be ready to be used but at your own risk.

Alternatives Michael Flaxman also discussed briefly on the [Stephan Livera podcast](https://diyhpl.us/wiki/transcripts/stephan-livera-podcast/2020-09-28-michael-flaxman-security-guide/) are [Caravan](https://github.com/unchained-capital/caravan) (Unchained Capital) and [Sparrow](https://github.com/sparrowwallet/sparrow).

These are all efforts to manage multisig for different hardware wallets with Bitcoin Core. I am not aware of any efforts from existing software wallets to expand their offering to multisig with other third party **software** wallets.

Answer (score 0):

The BitPay wallet IIRC has a very user-friendly implementation of m-of-n, even in its mobile wallet. It is also one of the most trustworthy wallets because of its matureness

Comment: I agree, but it already had an incident before with a nodejs dependency having a malware/backdoor. And lets face it, nobody audits nodejs dependencies because a simple project has 1000s of them.